# Why does turning on Application Insights on a App Service crash the app?

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have turned on Application Insights on my app service. Everytime I try to run the app or login using the app it gives an error:

```
An error has occurred. Please call support or your account manager if this error persists
```

When i looked in the Application errors under Logging,I get the following:

```
 System.ApplicationException: The trace listener AzureBlobTraceListener is disabled. 
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The SAS URL for the cloud storage account is not 
 specified. Use the environment variable 
 'DIAGNOSTICS_AZUREBLOBCONTAINERSASURL' to define it.
```

Im assuming I need to add the following in the Configuration of the App Service:

```
  {
    "name": "DIAGNOSTICS_AZUREBLOBCONTAINERSASURL",
    "value": <URL>,
    "slotSetting": true
  },
```

But what is the  and where can i find it ? Or is there a different error causing the app to crash once application insights is enabled, has anyone experienced this  ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250157/discussion-on-question-by-veronica-why-does-turning-on-application-insights-on-a).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see you have configured `DIAGNOSTICS_AZUREBLOBCONTAINERSASURL` without providing the value.

Get the `Blob service SAS URL` value from the Storage Account.

- In `Azure Portal` => `Create a Storage Account`.
- Initially the option to generate SAS is disabled for me.

[image]

- Navigate to your  `Storage Account` => `Shared access signature` = > select `Container` and `Object` checkboxes.

An option to `Generate SAS and connection string` will be enabled.

[image]

- Copy the `Blob service SAS URL` and provide the value in either local Configuration settings or in `Azure App Service` => `Configuration` =>  `Application Settings`.

[image]

***In Azure App Service Settings***

[image]

[image]

Save the settings and access the URL.

> My question before is that once i generate Generate SAS and Conection string and copy to clip board.

- Even if you generate the `SAS`  again, the value will be same till here - `https://yourSA.blob.core.windows.net/?sv=2021-06-08&ss=*****=co&sp=******&se=2022-12-05T14:`.
- Even we can add the SAS token in App settings automatically. Follow the below steps.
- In `Azure App Service` => `App Service logs` = >set `Application logging (Blob)` to `On` and continue the steps to add the Storage Account. If you don't have create a new Storage Account.

[image]

[image]

> "Unable to find mscorlib assembly reference:.

- Make sure you are using the latest package references.
- Update the framework version `4.7.2` to `4.8` in VS. Rebuild and Re-deploy the App.